# Optimization of loading images in the React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, api, optimization

I use the Unsplash API to search for images, and then output these images to div blocks. But there was such a problem - VERY slow and delayed loading of images. How can this be optimized or slightly speed up the loading of images?

```js
import './App.css';
import { useState, React } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [containerImgs, setContainerImgs] = useState([]);

  const searchInput = event => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  }

  async function getPhotos() {
    let response = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&query="+search+"&client_id={APP-SECRET}", {
      
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  
    let result = await response.json();
    if (result) {
      setContainerImgs(result.results);
      console.log(result.results)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input type="text" onChange={searchInput} />
      <input type="button" value="Go" onClick={getPhotos}/>
      <div className="images-container">
          {containerImgs.map(item =>
                <div key={item.id} className="card">
                  <img src={item.urls.full} content='fdsfsd' alt={item.alt_description}/>
                  <div className='user-info'>{item.user.name}</div>
                </div>
            ) }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Speed what up exactly?.   An `img` tag, no matter if it's React / or plain Javascript is controlled by the browser & how fast your internet is, & how fast the remote host responds.  There is nothing you can do in React to speed that up.  What you could maybe do is load the images on demand, eg. If you have 1000's images and as you scroll down, set the `img` tag at this point and not all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to quickly load an image - there are several types of images with different resolutions in the Unsplash API
I had a long loading of photo cards, because I upload the largest size of the picture
I set a smaller image upload size in the API and everything became much better